# How to display an image on VF PAGE uploaded via text rich field of custom object

Tags: visualforce, richtextarea

This is the code of the VF PAGE

```
<apex:page showHeader="false"  controller="Controller004">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <style>
    h1{font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; text-decoration:none;}
    </style>
    <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Record of avalaible Doctors">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!obj}" var="a">

     <apex:column headerValue="Name">
     <h1><apex:outputField value="{!a.Full_Name__c}" /></h1>
     </apex:column>
     <apex:column headerValue="Fee">
    <h1><apex:outputField value="{!a.Fee__c}"/></h1>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Schedule">
    <h1><apex:outputField value="{!a.schedule__c}"/></h1>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column >
    <apex:image value="{!a.ImageUpload__c}" />
    </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

AND this is the controller of the page:

```
global class Controller004{

    public List<Doctor__c> obj{get;set;}
    public Controller004(){
    obj = [select Full_Name__c, Fee__c, schedule__c, ImageUpload__c from Doctor__c];

    }
}
```

Comment: which field is richtextArea?

Comment: its ImageUpload__c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `ImageUpload__c` is rich text area

then don't use `apex:image` for `ImageUpload__c` field

Instead use `apex:outputField`

```
<apex:outputField value="{!a.ImageUpload__c}"/>
```

This will display your rich text area image.

when we use `apex:outputField` salssforce in there end use as richTextArea field.

Comment: Yes Ratan. It works. I also wanted to know how to customize the size of the image displayed on the page, It displays in its default size.

Comment: @Nishant if you check the doc for apex:outputField, you can use style attribute to  set height and width  .  [DOC LINK](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputField.htm)

Comment: @Nishant most welcome..