# Changing the width and height of image

Tags: apex, visualforce, images, richtextarea

I am using a visualforce page to save a record which has a Name field and a rich text area type field in it. I am using inputfield tag to get the data from user and save the record. The user has the ability to add a picture of any height/width and save the record, but I would like to control this behavior and reduce the image height/width. How can I do that? Below is my VF page and extension of it:

```
<apex:page standardController="Warehouse__c" extensions="WarehouseExtension">

 <apex:form >
 <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!savePicture}"/>
 <br></br>
 Image: <apex:inputfield value="{!Warehouse__c.Image__c}" rendered="{!status}"/>
<apex:outputfield value="{!Warehouse__c.Image__c}"  label="image" rendered="{!NOT(status)}"/>

<apex:image id="theImage" value="{!link}" width="300" height="200"/>

 Name: <apex:inputfield value="{!Warehouse__c.Name}"/>

 </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Extension:

```
public class WarehouseExtension {

    public Warehouse__c warehouse{get;set;}
    public boolean status{get;set;}
    ApexPages.StandardController stndcntrller{get;set;}
    public String link {get;set;}


    public WarehouseExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    warehouse = (Warehouse__c)controller.getrecord();
    warehouse = [select image__c from Warehouse__c where id=:warehouse.id];

    String firstSubString = warehouse.Image__c.substringBetween('<img', 'img>');
    System.debug('First substring: ' + firstSubString);

    String secondSubString = firstSubString.substringBetween('src="', '"');
    System.debug('Second substring: ' + secondSubString);

    link = secondSubString.replace('amp;', '');
    link = '"'+link+'"';
    System.debug('Link: ' + link);

    status = Boolean.valueOf( ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('status') );
    stndcntrller = controller;
    }

    public Pagereference savePicture(){

    stndcntrller.save();
    return null;
    }

}
```

I tried putting style in inputfield but the image size does not change when the image is saved in the record.

Comment: See these two posts for guidance: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114387/how-to-display-an-image-on-vf-page-uploaded-via-text-rich-field-of-custom-object?rq=1 and http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/123415/retrieving-an-image-from-rich-text-field?rq=1.

Comment: It helped, I got the image as i want .. 2nd link was useful